# Include dot operator in mysql like query

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to execute a query like this :-

```
First-Name Last-Name

Anand     Kumar

Mr.       Abc

select * from ( SELECT CONCAT(first_name ,' ', last_name) as full_name FROM `rm_users`) as a WHERE full_name LIKE '%mr abc%'
```

Here the like query does not take account the .(dot) in first name and gives no record found where it should.
Also i tried to used regexp query like this :-

```
select * from ( SELECT CONCAT(first_name ,' ', last_name) as full_name FROM `rm_users`) as a WHERE full_name REGEXP '^["abc"]'
```

In this second query it gives me both result as characters matches both records.Any solution for this please?

Comment: `REGEXP '^["abc"]'` says "start with (^) any of the characters `"abc` (with `"` unnecessarily duplicated).  It does not return the second line.

Comment: You can avoid using a nested query by using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need `.` remove it:

```
select * 
from ( SELECT CONCAT(first_name ,' ', last_name) as full_name 
       FROM rm_users) a 
WHERE REPLACE(full_name, '.', '') LIKE '%mr abc%';
```

Comment: Szozda I have accepted your answer but due to my low reputation it is not visible. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Varun.Kumar You need to check green tick under votes count.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this so just getting acquainted of the features.